# publish WSDL with cxf in mule

Tags: wsdl, cxf, mule

I want to publish my WSDL in MULE and use these codes:

```
<flow name="cxfProxy">
<http:inbound-endpoint
      address="http://localhost:8080/fed-ach"
      exchange-pattern="request-response">
    **<cxf:proxy-service
        wsdlLocation="http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?wsdl"
        namespace="http://wsf.cdyne.com/"
        service="FedACH"
        payload="body" />**
</http:inbound-endpoint>
<copy-properties propertyName="SOAPAction" />
<http:outbound-endpoint
      address="http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx"
      exchange-pattern="request-response">
    **<cxf:proxy-client payload="body" />**
</http:outbound-endpoint>
```

but In bold lines I have this error

> Element: Proxy-Service is not allowed to be child of element HTTP

Comment: Are you using Mule Studio or plain XML config?

Comment: Your config is correct and runs just fine. Don't get disturbed by Studio's bogus errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mule Studio shows errors for embedded elements (that's a bug) but your config looks fine and run provided namespaces are declared correctly